# Проблема с запуском linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Сегодня утром возникла проблема. При загрузке Linux Mint сваливается в busybox. В безопасном режиме вот что пишет:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файловая система btrfs, зашифрованная, если это имеет значение.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте сделать то, что предлагает вам сделать сфотографированный вами текст (если этому не помешает зашифрованная фс)